# BUILD.gn: how to add all .c files in one directory into sources

Tags: build-script, gn

how to add all .c files in one directory into sources.

this is not correct:

sources = [
"./fuzz_ioctl.c",
"./Secodefuzz/mutators/*.c",
"./Secodefuzz/common/*.c"
]

There is so many files in Secodefuzz/mutators and Secodefuzz/common.
I don't want to write all the file-name.

Answer (score 0):

GN does not natively support globs, and requires all source lists to be explicit.

It's not considered good GN style, but (for completeness) there is always [`exec_script`](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/main/docs/reference.md#func_exec_script). You can use `exec_script` to run a script at *configuration* time, investigate the filesystem, and return a list back to GN:

path/to/libfoo/BUILD.gn:

```
static_library("libfoo") {
  sources = exec_script("get_c_files.py", [], "list lines", [])
}
```

path/to/libfoo/get_c_files.py:

```
import pathlib
print("\n".join(str(f) for f in pathlib.Path().glob("*.c")))
```

Note that `exec_script` will run every time you invoke GN (including sub-tools like `desc` and `ls`), and can be a source of performance issues. Also, you can use the `--time` command-line option to profile your project.